# How to convert to NoData in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, nodata

I have the next code:

I am trying to make a mask (only one shape that I would like to use as an analysis region) with: all elevations less than 4.100 meters (from DEM), all area with water (NDWI) and all slopes less than 15 degrees (from DEM).

I could mask it but I don't know how to join the three layers and I dont know either how to convert the 255 value to NoData.

How can I do it to insert all this variables in one layer and then use that layer as a region?

```js
var region= MNDWI_DPS

//NDWI

var NDWI = ee.Image('MODIS/MCD43A4_NDWI/MCD43A4_005_2016_05_16')

var visualize = NDWI.visualize({bands: ['NDWI'], min: -1, max: 0}).clip(region);


//DEM+SLOPE

var MDE = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')

var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003'));

var visualize1 = MDE.visualize({bands: ['elevation'], min: 0, max: 4100}).clip(region);

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(MDE);

var visualize2 = slope.visualize({bands: ['slope'], min: 0, max: 15}).clip(region)

Map.addLayer(visualize.clip(region))
Map.addLayer(visualize1.clip(region))
Map.addLayer(visualize2.clip(region))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, this is what you want.

```js
//NDWI
// NDWI produces an image in which the positive 
// data values are typically open water areas (https://deltas.usgs.gov/fm/data/data_ndwi.aspx)

var NDWI = ee.Image('MODIS/MCD43A4_NDWI/MCD43A4_005_2016_05_16')
var watermask = NDWI.gte(0)
var water = NDWI.updateMask(watermask)

//DEM+SLOPE

var MDE = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(MDE);

print("MDE", MDE.bandNames())
print("terrain", terrain.bandNames())

// elevation less than 4100 m
var less_4100_mask = terrain.select('elevation').lte(4100)
var less_4100 = terrain.select('elevation').updateMask(less_4100_mask)

// slope less than 15°
var less_15_deg_mask = terrain.select('slope').lte(15)
var less_15_deg = terrain.select('slope').updateMask(less_15_deg_mask)

// final image
var final = water.addBands(less_4100).addBands(less_15_deg).clip(region)

Map.addLayer(final)
```

But I think you should use a better approach for water mask, in my case *NDWI* did not throw good results.